# How to configure PyTorch on CUDA 11.7 with NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080

Tags: pytorch, torch

I have installed lots of PyTorch versions to configure PyTorch with `Cuda 11.7` but unfortunately, it returns `torch.cuda.is_available()` is False.

**Not working on CUDA 11.7**

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia
conda install pytorch==1.10.1 torchvision==0.11.2 torchaudio==0.10.1 cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0
pip install torch==1.7.1+cu110 torchvision==0.8.2+cu110 torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

(pytesseract) cvpr@cvpr:$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

**Conda Environment:**

```
Python 3.9.16
CUDA 11.7
```

Which PyTorch version is suitable for the above conda environment?